# Evaluation of the integral

Tags: integration, exponential-function

How to evaluate the following integral?
$$\int\frac{e^{-x}dx}{\sqrt x+ae^{-x}}$$
where $a$ is a constant.

Comment: I see no reason to think this integral is elementary, even when $a=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are ready to use special functions, the only way I can see is
$$I=\int\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt x+ae^{-x}}\,dx=\int \frac{dx}{a+e^x \sqrt{x}}$$
$$\frac{dx}{a+e^x \sqrt{x}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n  \left(\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^{n+1}\,a^n$$
$$I=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n a^n \int\left(\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^{n+1}\,dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n a^n J_n$$
$$J_n=\int \left(\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^{n+1}\,dx=-x^{\frac{1-n}{2}} E_{\frac{n+1}{2}}((n+1) x)$$ where appear the exponential integral function.

**Edit**

For illustration, using $a=1$ and integrating between $1$ and $10$, the partial sums (up to $p$) would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & \text{partial sum} \\
0 & 0.27879186 \\
 1 & 0.22989135 \\
 2 & 0.24162796 \\
 3 & 0.23842973 \\
 4 & 0.23936339 \\
 5 & 0.23907879 \\
 6 & 0.23916815 \\
 7 & 0.23913948 \\
 8 & 0.23914883 \\
 9 & 0.23914574 \\
 10 & 0.23914677
\end{array}
\right)$$ while the "exact" result obtained by numerical integration would be  $0.23914652$.